# getting error 400 with axios post request & undefined error

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios

I'm making a project to store the data in mysql using react-native. and node.js server
but i faced two problems One is TypeError in object : undefined and the other is getting error 400 with axios post request. I trying to another way for solve second problem (chage the param to formData - but this is doesn't work error 404) Sorry if this is a stupid mistake, as i am new to working with react native and node.js.

React native code

```
onPress={() => {
                    AsyncStorage.getItem("pubKey").then(pubKey => {
                      AsyncStorage.getItem("name").then(name => {
                        const {
                            data: { article }
                          } = axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:4000/apply",null,{
                            params: {
                              articleId: id,
                              apubKey: pubKey,
                              name: name,
                            },
                            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
                          });
                          alert('지원 확인')
                          console.log(article)
                      })
                    })
                  }}
```

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_axios$post.data.article')]
> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 400]

node.js (apply.js)

```
router.post("/", function (req, res) {
console.log("req.body.params: ",req.body)
console.log("req: ",req)
Article.findAll({
    attributes: ["id", "db_pubKey", "db_title", "db_wtype"],

    where: {
        id: req.body.articleId
    }
})
    .then(result => {
        console.log("result : " + JSON.stringify(result));

        let DB2 = JSON.stringify(result);
        let DB1 = JSON.parse(DB2);
        let DB = DB1[0];
        if (DB) {
            console.log("DB", DB);

            Apply.create({
                db_apubKey: req.body.params.apubKey,
                db_articleId: req.body.params.articleId,
                db_opubKey: DB.db_pubKey,
                db_title: DB.db_title,
                db_wtype: DB.db_wtype,
                db_name: req.body.params.name,
                db_accept: null
            })
                .then(result => {
                    console.log("result : " + result);
                    res.status(201).json({ result: 1 });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error("err : " + err);
                });
        } else {
            res.json({ result: 0 });
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error("err : " + err);
        next(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Not the cause of your 400 response but you need to await the result of the Axios promise before you start pulling `data` out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All API calls are asynchronous, so you need to handle an asynchronous action with proper strategies like `async/await` or `then/catch` method.

With the `async/await` method:

```
onPress={async () => {
  try {
      const pubKey = await AsyncStorage.getItem("pubKey")
      const name = await AsyncStorage.getItem("name")
    
      const result = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:4000/apply", null, {
        params: {
          articleId: id,
          apubkey: pubKey,
          name: name,
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
      })
         
      const article = await result?.data?.article
    
      alert('지원 확인')
      console.log(article)

  } catch (error) {
    // do proper action on error/failure cases
    console.log(error)
  }
}}
```

**Note:** don't forget to use `catch` method for your API calls.

**Note:** as a side note, you can't call an `http` URL in production application, it must be an `https`

**Note:** you might need to specify the `article` type and pass it.

About the 400 error on your backend side:
change this line `router.post("/", function (req, res) {` to :

```
router.post("/apply", function (req, res) {
 // rest of the codes ...
```

You've forgotten to add your API name correctly.

Comment: I try to reimplementation by  your implementation. As the result, Type error : undefined is fixed But error 400 still occurs `Request failed with status code 400
at node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
at node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:16:9 in settle
- ... 10 more stack frames from framework internals`

Comment: I've updated my answer with your backend issue. please take a look @mono

Comment: I checked your answer then change my code , but this time, an error of 404 occurred. @novonimo

Comment: You added some `console.log` on your  `router.post("/apply")` function, the logs are important here, what did you see on calling apply API ?  @mono

Comment: also check this section `    where: {
        id: req.body.articleId
    }`, You sent the `id` with params but here you are getting the id from the body, please check the implementation and logs. @mono

Comment: I added some `console.log` in `router.point("./apply")` but it doesn't work 
`router.post("/apply", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);` node js server returns `POST /apply 404`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238661/discussion-between-mono-and-novonimo).